# Google Datastore returns incomplete data via official client library for nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-datastore

Here some information about context of the problem I facing:

1. we have a semi-structured (JSON from node.js backend) data in datastore.
2. after saving an entity,
3. and getting a list of entities about them soon and even a while later,
4. returned data does not have one indexed property
5. I can find the entity by that property value.

I use Google Datastore via node.js client library. `@google-cloud/datastore: "^2.0.0"`.

How it can be possible? I understood when due to eventual consistency some updates can be incompletely written etc. But when I getting same inconsistency - lack of whole property of entity saved e. g. hour ago?
I gone through scenario multiple times for same kind multiple times.
I do not have such issues with other kinds or other properties of that kind.

How I can avoid this type of issues with Google Datastore?

Answer (score 0):

Answer for anyone who may encounter with such issue.
We mostly do not use any DTO (data-transfer objects) or any other wrappers for most of our kinds in this project, but for this one a DTO has been used, mostly to be sure the result objects have default values for properties omitted/absent in entity which usually happens for entities created by older version of code.

After reviewing my own code more carefully, I found a piece of code which is out of sync with other related pieces of code - there was no a line to copy this property from entity to the DTO object.

Side note: Actually all this situation remind me a story or meme about a guy who claimed he found a bug in compiler just because he was not able to find a mistake he made in his code.